# Выполнение соответствующих запросов по нажатиям ссылок

Tags: php

Такой вопрос, как с помощью $quarry и if, а также else достичь следующего: в странице test.php мы выдаем результат запроса

```
select * from table where sex = boy
```

но в этом же файле есть ссылка на результат запроса

```
select * from table where sex = girl
```

а теперь вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы результат первого и второго запроса показывался на странице одного файла, то есть test.php; есть ссылки 1 и 2, когда нажимаешь 1, снизу выполняет первый запрос, когда нажимаешь 2, внизу выполняет второй запрос?

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский литературный, пожалуйста. Потому что если я отвечу, что надо сделать ключ гет массива, в котором параметр  запроса, а по нему делать иф и в ифе, если бой, то один а, если герл, то другой запрос, вы же меня не поймете ок?

Comment: Воспитываешь? =)

Comment: Вообще я почти уверен, что если по-нормальному оформить вопрос и прочитать про `$_GET` пару предложений, решение пришло бы само) Но да, что-то типа, хайль Розенталь)

ЗЫ: сам довольно часто форматирую, когда устаю - вот такое получается)

Comment: сам довольно часто форматирую// см мой статус мессадж. ;)  
Это не хайль Розенталь. Это уже грамма наци! =) Но и правильно. Поддерживаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href='test.php?sex=boy'>BOYS HERE</a>
<a href='test.php?sex=girl'>GIRLS HERE</a>

if(isset($_REQUEST['sex'])){
switch($_REQUEST['sex']){
 case 'boy': $sql = "select * from table where sex = boy"; break;
 case 'girl': $sql = "select * from table where sex = girl"; break;
 default: $sql = "select * from table where 1";
}

$res = mysql_query($sql);

//обработка $res

}
```